# Could I use array slicing instead of creating vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

This is not homework! 
Simply example to complex problem. 
Right now I take arrays, create vectors, then use equation with vectors as inputs. 
Everything works fine. But, wondering if I could skip vector creation and use the array slicing to the samething.

```
import numpy as np

a = [[ 7.,  5.], [ 9.,  3.], [ 7.,  2.], [ 7.,  8.], [ 6.,  8.], [ 3.,  2.]]
a = np.asarray(list(a), np.float)

x = np.asarray(a[:,(0)], np.float)
y = np.asarray(a[:,(1)], np.float)

foo = 5*x+y*y 
print foo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 7.,  5.], [ 9.,  3.], [ 7.,  2.], [ 7.,  8.], [ 6.,  8.], [ 3.,  2.]])

foo = 5*a[:,0] + a[:,1]**2
```